# Having trouble with my finals. Code keeps looping back to my ordering menu and wont show my total price

Tags: c++

I am super new to programming. For my finals, I was told to make a program that consists of if else while do and arrays. I'm really confused as to why when in my program, where I have to calculate the prices, it doesn't show and it just loops back to my ordering code. Any ideas?

```
                cout <<"COKE \t\t\t-Php 30 \t" ;
                cout << setw (50) <<" Carbonated softdrink by Coca-Cola Company in 2.5L."<<endl;

                cout <<"SPRITE  \t\t-Php 30 \t";
                cout<< setw(50) <<" A colorless, lemon and lime-flavored soft drink in 2.5L."<<endl;

                cout <<"ICED TEA\t\t-Php 30 \t ";
                cout <<setw (20) <<"Houseblend iced tea in 1L pitcher."<<endl;

                cout <<"COFFEE \t\t\t-Php 25 \t";
                cout << setw (55) << " A brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans in a cup."<<endl;

                cout <<"BOTTLED WATER \t\t-Php 20 \t";
                cout <<setw (25) <<" A purified drinking water in 500mL." <<endl;
                cout <<"-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" <<endl <<endl;

                cout <<"1 \t Order Now" <<endl;
                cout <<"0 \t Back" <<endl <<endl;

                cout <<"Enter the number of your choice: ";
                cin >> ow;

                    if (ow==1){

                        history[length] = "Order";
                        length += 1;
                        while(ow!=0){
                        system ("cls");

                        cout <<"\nRICE MEAL " <<setw (30) << "DRINKS\n" <<endl;
                        cout <<"Hotsilog \t-Php 45 \t" <<setw(15) <<"Coke \t\t\t-Php 30" <<endl;
                        cout <<"Tocilog \t-Php 45 \t" << setw(15) <<"Sprite  \t\t-Php 30" <<endl;
                        cout <<"Tapsilog \t-Php 45 \t" << setw(15) <<"Iced Tea \t\t-Php 30" << endl;
                        cout <<"Porksilog \t-Php 50 \t" << setw(15) <<"Coffee \t\t\t-Php 25" <<endl;
                        cout <<"Chickensilog \t-Php 55 \t" <<setw (15) <<"Bottled Water \t\t-Php 20" << endl;

                        string product [50];
                        string note [50];
                        int qty [10];
                        int price [10];
                        int e;
                        int totalprice = 0;

                        cout <<"\nNumber of Product Name you will need: ";
                        cin>> e;

                        cin.ignore();

                        cout <<"\nFill in the order form based on above.\n";
                        cout <<"Orders not mention above will be disregarded.\n\n";

                            for (int i=0; i<e; i++){
                                cout <<"Enter the 'Name' of the product you will buy: ";
                                getline (cin, product[i]);

                                cout <<"Additional Note (Press Enter if no additional note): ";
                                getline (cin, note [i]);

                                cout <<"Quantity: ";
                                cin >> qty[i] ;

                                cout <<"Price: ";
                                cin >> price[i];
                                cin.ignore();
                            system ("cls");
                             }
                            // system ("cls");

                            cout <<"Your Product's List " <<endl << endl;
                            for (int j=0; j<e; j++){
                                cout <<"Product Name: " << product [j] <<endl;
                                cout <<"Quantity:" << qty[j]<< endl;
                                cout <<"Price: "<< price [j] << endl <<endl;

                                    totalprice = totalprice + (qty [j]*price[j]);  

                                cout << "Total Price: " <<totalprice;
                            } \\This is the line that I am having trouble with, it won't show up when I enter the number of food I input.


                        }   
                    }

                }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Next step: Learn, how to debug programs. ;-) [Visual Studio debugger documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/?view=vs-2019), [GDB (Step by Step Introduction)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gdb-step-by-step-introduction/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve], with emphasis on the minimal part.

Comment: I am with Some. But do not overstress the "minimal", I definitly want it also to be reproducable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following:

```cpp
while (ow != 0) {
    system ("cls");
```

In the end of your `while` loop you calculate and print `totalprice`. After that it loops around, and because you haven't changed the value of `ow` in the `while` loop it's still not equal to `0`, hence, you get into an infinite loop. The reason you don't see `totalprice` printed out because when you loop around you instantly call `system ("cls")` that deletes `totalprice` from the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are your best friends when it comes to making your text more readable, variable names are also very important. I modified your code a little so that you can observe what a big difference it makes:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void display_main_menu();
void display_header();

int main() {
    int selected_option;

    display_main_menu();
    cin >> selected_option;

    if (selected_option == 1) {
        while(selected_option != 0) {
            string product [50];
            string note [50];
            int qty [10];
            int price [10];
            int e;
            int totalprice = 0;

            cout <<"\nNumber of Product Name you will need: ";
            cin >> e;

            cout <<"\nFill in the order form based on above.\n";
            cout <<"Orders not mention above will be disregarded.\n\n";

            for (int counter = 0; counter < e; counter++){
                cout <<"Enter the 'Name' of the product you will buy: ";
                getline (cin, product[counter]);

                cout <<"Additional Note (Press Enter if no additional note): ";
                getline (cin, note[counter]);

                cout <<"Quantity: ";
                cin >> qty[counter] ;

                cout <<"Price: ";
                cin >> price[counter];
                system ("cls");
            }

            cout <<"Your Product's List " << endl << endl;
            for (int counter = 0; counter < e; counter++){
                cout <<"Product Name: " << product[counter] <<endl;
                cout <<"Quantity:" << qty[counter]<< endl;
                cout <<"Price: "<< price[counter] << endl <<endl;

                totalprice += (qty[counter] * price[counter]);  
                cout << "Total Price: " << totalprice;
            }

            cin >> selected_option;
            system ("cls");
        }   
    }
    return 0;
}

void display_header() {
    system ("cls");
    cout <<"\nRICE MEAL " << "DRINKS\n" <<endl;
    cout <<"Hotsilog \t-Php 45 \t" <<"Coke \t\t\t-Php 30" <<endl;
    cout <<"Tocilog \t-Php 45 \t" <<"Sprite  \t\t-Php 30" <<endl;
    cout <<"Tapsilog \t-Php 45 \t" <<"Iced Tea \t\t-Php 30" << endl;
    cout <<"Porksilog \t-Php 50 \t" <<"Coffee \t\t\t-Php 25" <<endl;
    cout <<"Chickensilog \t-Php 55 \t" <<"Bottled Water \t\t-Php 20" << endl;
}

void display_main_menu() {
    cout <<"COKE \t\t\t-Php 30 \t" ;
    cout <<" Carbonated softdrink by Coca-Cola Company in 2.5L."<<endl;

    cout <<"SPRITE  \t\t-Php 30 \t";
    cout <<" A colorless, lemon and lime-flavored soft drink in 2.5L."<<endl;

    cout <<"ICED TEA\t\t-Php 30 \t ";
    cout <<"Houseblend iced tea in 1L pitcher."<<endl;

    cout <<"COFFEE \t\t\t-Php 25 \t";
    cout << " A brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans in a cup."<<endl;

    cout <<"BOTTLED WATER \t\t-Php 20 \t";
    cout <<" A purified drinking water in 500mL." <<endl;
    cout <<"-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" <<endl <<endl;

    cout <<"1 \t Order Now" <<endl;
    cout <<"0 \t Back" <<endl <<endl;

    cout <<"Enter the number of your choice: ";
}
```

You can divide this even further to separate functions, I didn't do it to not scare you with pointers.